# Shared Interface Implementation in Remote Proxy Pattern

Tags: dart

I'm brushing up on my design patterns knowledge by going through them in Dart, and I'm currently working on the remote proxy pattern. As I understand, the pattern implies a shared interface between the *real* object residing on a server machine, and the proxy object on a client machine.

I've managed to get all the networking between the client and server working fine, and i've set up a simple RPC API with dart's `HttpServer` and `HttpClient`, but there's one thing that's bugging me. The methods on the proxy object must be asynchronous because of the networking involved, but the *real* object's methods aren't asynchronous. It would appear that this makes it impossible for them to share an interface, and thus functional consistency between the two classes isn't guaranteed by the type system.

Is there a way to implement some kind of a future version of a certain interface in dart? I don't mean something that returns `Future<SomeInterface>`, but something where the methods of `SomeInterface` are implemented asynchronously with `Future` return types. What i'm looking for is something like:

```dart
abstract class IShared {
  int foo();
} 

class Bar implements IShared {
  @override
  int foo() {
    // perform work here
    return 0;
  }
}

class BarProxy implements async IShared {
  // Currently an invalid override
  @override
  Future<int> foo() async {
    // perform async work here
    return 0;
  }
}
```

I'm aware that `Future<IShared>` implies something completely different entirely, but is there anything that could help implement what I want? Maybe i'm being too strict with requiring a shared interface between the *real* object and the proxy, but that's how it's always implemented in class diagrams.

Or perhaps there's a good pattern that i'm missing that can achieve this.

To be clear, I don't want to make the methods of the shared interface and non proxy object `async` with `Future` returns if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a case for [`FutureOr`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-async/FutureOr-class.html) which you can use to represent the case where you want to be able to return a object or same object packed inside an `Future`:

```
import 'dart:async';

abstract class IShared {
  FutureOr<int> foo();
}

class Bar implements IShared {
  @override
  int foo() {
    // perform work here
    return 0;
  }
}

class BarProxy implements IShared {
  @override
  Future<int> foo() async {
    // perform async work here
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Just what i was looking for. I need to look into `FutureOr` a bit more. Seems like it's useful when you sometimes want to return a cached value synchronously but if this is not possible then you can return an `Future`.